# How configure cookbook maven in chef node?

Tags: java, ruby, maven, chef-infra, cookbook

The source for question can be easy found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420956/how-run-cookbook-with-dependencies-in-chef). So I run `knife cookbook site install maven` and then `knife cookbook upload myCookbook --include-dependencie`

But after run

```
knife bootstrap 192.168.1.37 --ssh-user root --ssh-password '123456' --sudo --use-sudo-password --node-name node-with-maven-run --run-list 'recipe[myCookbook]'
```

I got

```
No such file or directory - mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get -DgroupId=org.springframework -DartifactId=spring-context -Dversion=4.0.4.RELEASE -Dpackaging=jar  -Ddest=/tmp/chef_maven_lwrp20141212-27453-ocmoxb/spring-context-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar -DremoteRepositories=http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ -Dtransitive=false
```

It turns out that `maven` simply not installed on `192.168.1.37`. How can I install maven before run maven cookbook?

**P.S.**

It is very strange that cookbook does not test itself whether maven is installed or not.

Comment: Please include your recipe code and the output from Chef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a depends 'maven' in the metadata.rb file won't do anything more than load the cookbook.

You'll have to include the recipe too in your cookbook recipe.

Something like 
`include_recipe 'maven'` at top of your myCookbook default recipe should do.