# How see what exactly cookbook were uploaded fail?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I try to upload cookbook with dependencies, here is a log:

```
[root@redhat cookbooks]# knife cookbook upload reference-app --include-dependencies
Uploading my-cookbook  [0.1.0]
Uploading maven          [1.2.0]
Uploading hipsnip-jetty  [0.9.0]
Uploading ark            [0.9.0]
Uploading java           [1.29.0]
Uploading windows        [1.34.8]
Uploading 7-zip          [1.0.2]
Uploading chef_handler   [1.1.6]
WARNING: Uploaded 8 cookbooks ok but 2 cookbooks upload failed.
```

It is all log. Is there a way to sse what cookbook were failed exactly?

Comment: you may try adding a `-V` (uppercase v) at end of the command to have a verbose output from knife. Maybe the output could be improved in this case to show failed uploads too. (Seems there's no open ticket for this on [github](https://github.com/opscode/chef/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+knife))

Comment: I know it doesn't answer the question but I would highly recommend using Berkshelf to manage cookbook dependencies. It will do a much better job of managing a complex tree of dependencies. See example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420956/how-run-cookbook-with-dependencies-in-chef/27432499#27432499

Answer (score 0):

Using the verbose flag will show you why it didn't upload correctly.

For instance I added some bad code to the apt cookbook...

```
[scarman@coldlight cookbooks]$ knife cookbook upload apt --include-dependencies -n -V
Uploading apt            [2.6.0]
INFO: Validating ruby files
FATAL: Cookbook file recipes/default.rb has a ruby syntax error:
FATAL: /home/scarman/DevOps/cookbooks/apt/recipes/default.rb:29: `@#' is not allowed as an instance variable name
FATAL: /home/scarman/DevOps/cookbooks/apt/recipes/default.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting '('
FATAL: uha897*@S::@#!!
FATAL:             ^
```

And also turned my internet off for a moment...

```
[scarman@coldlight cookbooks]$ knife cookbook upload apt --include-dependencies -n -V
ERROR: Error connecting to https://api.opscode.com/organizations/cls-chef/cookbooks?num_versions=all, retry 1/5
ERROR: Error connecting to https://api.opscode.com/organizations/cls-chef/cookbooks?num_versions=all, retry 2/5
ERROR: Error connecting to https://api.opscode.com/organizations/cls-chef/cookbooks?num_versions=all, retry 3/5
ERROR: Error connecting to https://api.opscode.com/organizations/cls-chef/cookbooks?num_versions=all, retry 4/5
ERROR: Error connecting to https://api.opscode.com/organizations/cls-chef/cookbooks?num_versions=all, retry 5/5
ERROR: Network Error: Error connecting to https://api.opscode.com/organizations/cls-chef/cookbooks?num_versions=all - getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Check your knife configuration and network settings
```

That should hopefully provide you with more insight as to why it's failing.